# Tried install of Ubuntu onto Gateway NV79 = ends up with dark screen

Tags: gateway

Okay, I'm a total NEWBIE, so I apologize in advance if I don't word this correctly.  :)

I am trying to install Ubuntu (tried several versions) onto a Gateway NV79 laptop, using a USB drive.  Everything goes fine until I hit "Enter" to install Ubuntu onto hard drive - I get the initial "rolling lines" indicating it is attempting install, then my screen goes dark - not blank or black - I can barely make out various windows if I hold up screen to light.  I've tried the brightness hotkeys, to no avail.  I tried to look in forums, but they are currently down due to security breach.

This was my first attempt at actually installing  Ubuntu, although I have used it numerous times to rescue data from a crashed Windows system.  I am NOT a techie, nor do I understand much about hardware/OS...what can I say, my computer knowledge is LIMITED, to say the least.  :)  If I attach another monitor to my laptop, BOTH screens suddenly work perfectly, but instead of being able to install Ubuntu, I am getting error messages and it terminates install.

Is there a relatively simple way to correct this issue or is it something that will require someone with much more computer savvy than myself to address?

Thank you for any assistance you may be able to provide.  Have a great day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

During boot you can pass some options.
Try the option `acpi_backlight=vendor`.